# Backup a Lacie 2 Big NAS on a remote linux server

Tags: linux, backup, sftp, rsync, nas

I want to backup my Lacie OS 3.x NAS 4TB on a remote server using the native web interface.

The best solution for me would be to use rsync, unfortunatly i do not have ssh shell access on the disk.

I tried to backup my device with a "compatible rsync server" but without success :

Going to backup > New Backup, Network backup, selecting all my shares, Rsync compatible server.

I'm typing working ssh credentials of my debian backup server (which have rsync 3.0.9) and it doesn't list any rsync destination so i can't continue the backup shcedule.

The web interface also provide a solution on a "NetBackup Server", but i don't know how I can install it on Debian (not sure it's the symantec product).

Also, the NAS provide a working SFTP access, but i only want to backup modified files (Because backup 4TB each time is a bit greedy).

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help, i finaly discover that Rsync could be used as a daemon with preconfigured destinations :

On my debian side, by creating a /etc/rsyncd.conf containning

```
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid

[documents]
    path = /home/juan/Documents
    comment = The documents folder of Juan
    uid = juan
    gid = juan
    read only = no
    list = yes
    auth users = rsyncclient
    secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
    hosts allow = 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```

/etc/rsyncd.secrets

```
rsyncclient:passWord
user:password
```

Do not forget

```
chmod 600 /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

And then launch

```
rsync --daemon
```

After that, i can finaly view rsync destination when configuring Backup on my Nas.

Source : http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2011/01/running-rsync-as-a-daemon.html